# Ubuntu 14.04, SSH very slow when not running Unity

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.
I have it so that it boots up into the text-based login.
I will only be using SSH to gain access to the computer.
When I logged in via SSH, all key presses take a long time to appear (couple of seconds), and this is not normal.

I have found that once I have logged in via SSH and I run:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

then SSH returns to normal functional speed.

So something is going on with `lightdm` but I'm not sure what.

So I did a bit of debugging. Before restarting lightdm and I do `ps aux | grep lightdm` I get

```
sebasti+  1555  0.0  0.1  15948  2272 pts/0    S+   23:48   0:00 grep lightdm
```

and if I run `ps aux | grep lightdm` after restarting lightdm I get

```
root      1596  0.1  0.3 292628  7188 ?        Ssl  23:49   0:00 lightdm
root      1612  5.1  1.5 436204 30656 tty7     Ssl+ 23:49   0:01 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
root      1619  0.0  0.3 168312  6376 ?        Sl   23:49   0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 15
sebasti+  2261  0.0  0.1  15952  2328 pts/0    S+   23:49   0:00 grep lightdm
```

I don't know why this fixes the problem, but it is very annoying to have to run `sudo service lightdm restart` and enter my password every time I SSH in.
I tried to add `sudo service lightdm restart` to `/etc/rc.local` in the hope that it would run the command automatically on startup but it didn't work.

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable X11 forwarding when you ssh into the server.

```
ssh -x user@server
```

Options for ssh vary so check for your ssh.